# Looping through an array objects within another array of objects

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, object, loops

I have an array of object called `objStud` within it has another array

how do I loop and display them?

Here is an image that you can see how `objStud` is like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use nested `foreach` statements

```
foreach (Student stud in objStud)
{
    foreach (Fee in stud.Fees)
    {
        // Do something with stud and/or fee
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 since the user doesn't even know how to loop, the other example is probably too complex for him to understand.

Comment: I would also add here that if you decide to edit (add / remove) from the arrays you would need to switch to a for loop.  Since the OP is definitely new this would be good information to pass on as well.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) to flatten first:

```
foreach(var fee in objStud.SelectMany(x => x.Fees))
{
}
```

Comment: Linq is great, but perhaps slightly advanced for the OP given the question.

Comment: @EricJ.: then, it's time for OP to learn LINQ ;), it's not much advanced. though

Comment: I disagree.  It's important to understand the concept of nested loops before using an abstraction that hides that detail.  Without the fundamental understanding, the OP will learn to do things without understanding *why* they work the way they do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "foreach" in looping and displaying the values.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) is a very easy and good example on how to access the data that you want to display.

This will also teach you the concept behind array. Have fun!